# Is there something like glob but for URLs, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, url, glob

I need to match URLs against string patterns but I want to avoid RegExp to keep the patterns simple and readable.

I'd like to be able to have patterns like `http://*.example.org/*`, which should be equivalent of `/^http:\/\/.*\.example.org\/.*$/` in RegExp. That RegExp should also illustrate why I want to keep it more readable.

Basically I'd like glob-like patterns that work for URLs. The Problem is: normal glob implementations treat `/` as a delimiter. That means, `http://foo.example.org/bar/bla` wouldn't match my simple pattern.

So, an implementation of glob that can ignore slashes would be great. Is there such a thing or something similar?

Comment: Maybe one of the following wildcard libraries would be of help: https://github.com/sindresorhus/matcher
https://github.com/AlexKamaev/match-url-wildcard
https://github.com/gamache/fuzzyurl.js

Answer (score 4):

You can start with a function like this for glob like behavior:

```
function glob(pattern, input) {
    var re = new RegExp(pattern.replace(/([.?+^$[\]\\(){}|\/-])/g, "\\$1").replace(/\*/g, '.*'));
    return re.test(input);
}
```

Then call it as:

```
glob('http://*.example.org/*', 'http://foo.example.org/bar/bla');
true
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I would probably have to start with, if I'd have to implement it myself. I'd prefer a library that already does this, though.

Comment: I'd also like to avoid regular expressions because handling escaping properly is a nightmare (if not impossible) in JavaScript's RegExp.

Comment: To clarify, if someone stumbles on this: Handling escaped characters is kind-of possible but still very complex and not really "correct" in some regex implementations. The JavaScript RegExp can't do this at all due to the lack of "negative lookbehind".

Comment: hi, I am a bit late for the party I guess.. wondering if you end up writing the code yourself or you found a reliable library. https://www.npmjs.com/package/calmcard is deprecated now, and looks like it's not used by many anyway

Comment: @mikey The following should be appropriate If anyone can find a JS implementation of it: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns